# How to make this client side code a server side code?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, code-behind, serverside-javascript

I have wrote a client side code in server side code like this:

```
 strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<link rel='shortcut icon' href='/EVServer/Images/favicon.ico'/> \n";
```

This code looks like this in client side:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/EVServer/Images/favicon.ico" />
```

On executing the HTML file dynamically it comes like this:

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' href='/EVServer/Images/favicon.ico'/>
```

What to add in code behind so that i can get like this in my HTML file dynamically.Like this below in C#:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/EVServer/Images/favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the favicon from code behind.Just add a `runat="server"` attribute to the `<link>` element and you will be able to access it from code.

**.ASPX:**

```
<link id="favIcon" runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" />
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    favIcon.Attributes["href"] = "/EVServer/Images/favicon.ico";
}
```